# why can't I import cupy-cuda101 correctly?

Tags: python, linux, cupy

I'm running into issues with importing CuPy after pip installing cupy-cuda101. I've ensured that I'm using the correct CUDA version available and that I only have one version of CuPy installed.
The error code are like follows:

```
import cupy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cupy import _core  # NOQA
  File "/home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy/_core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
  File "cupy/_core/core.pyx", line 1, in init cupy._core.core
  File "/home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy/cuda/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import compiler  # NOQA
  File "/home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cupy.cuda import device
  File "cupy/cuda/device.pyx", line 10, in init cupy.cuda.device
ImportError: /home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol cusparseConstrainedGeMM_bufferSize version libcusparse.so.10 not defined in file libcusparse.so.10 with link time reference

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_msg) from e
ImportError: CuPy is not correctly installed.

If you are using wheel distribution (cupy-cudaXX), make sure that the version of CuPy you installed matches with the version of CUDA on your host.
Also, confirm that only one CuPy package is installed:
  $ pip freeze

If you are building CuPy from source, please check your environment, uninstall CuPy and reinstall it with:
  $ pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

original error: /home1/xuchenhao/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol cusparseConstrainedGeMM_bufferSize version libcusparse.so.10 not defined in file libcusparse.so.10 with link time reference

My environments are: 
python=3.7.6 
GCC=7.3.0 
cuda=10.1.168 
cupy-cuda101=9.5.0
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: cupy-cuda101 binary wheel is not compatible with cuda 10.1 update 1.
You need to install cuda 10.1 update 2 or build cupy from source.
It is not possible to distribute a CuPy wheel that is compatible with both, so we choose to support only update 2.

https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/3918

Comment: emmm, I'm using remote service and I can't update cuda, are there any other sulutions?

Comment: The only option would be to build CuPy from source or install the regular sdist package. `pip install cupy`

Comment: I used the `pip install cupy` , but the system told me that thete have no matched distribution for cupy.